# Trouble running a .x86 file

Tags: 14.04

I've been having trouble running programs on Ubuntu. I was browsing indie games on a website, and what do you know, they have a Linux version! I downloaded the zip, extracted it to a folder, and went into properties and checked the "Allow executing file as program" box.

Being a Windows user at heart, I double clicked the executable. However, no matter what I do, no window pops up. I tried running from the terminal, too, and it tells me "No such file or directory". Please help!